# webapp2 route containing regex does not work

Tags: python, regex, google-app-engine, webapp2

I want to make use of the following regex in some of my routes to enable the formatting of the response content:

```
    RedirectRoute(r'/mypath/<:|json|xml>', handler=myhandler, handler_method='mymethod', name='myhandler=mymethod', methods=['POST'], strict_slash=True),
```

The desired functionality of the above snippet would be:

- POST /mypath returns html
- POST /mypath/json returns application/json
- POST /mypath/xml returns application/xml

Any ideas how this can be done?

Comment: How about `r'/mypath/<:(json|xml)>'`?

Comment: This configuration does not support the first case `POST /mypath returns html`.

Comment: Oh. right. `r'/mypath(/json|/xml)*'`?

Comment: This is not the correct syntax for regex in webapp2 routes. Bad request error.

Comment: Bad request means the url is right, but the request is not.

Answer (score 0):

Route class [doesn't](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/routing.html#guide-routing-the-url-template) support regular expressions outside of it's internal  variables. So try

```
RedirectRoute('/mypath<format:|/xml|/json>', handler=myhandler, handler_method='mymethod', name='myhandler=mymethod', methods=['POST'], strict_slash=True)
```

All you need is to strip leading slash from received value in request handler.

Name `<format:` for the variable is needed because I had an `Bad request` error if it is blank (<:) in case of `/mypath/` (with ending slash) request. Error happens when webapp tries to create URL for redirect to `/mypath` as strict_slash=True. I suppose you had same error.